# How to properly implement seperation of access levels in your web api?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Currently I recieve claims in my controller, these claims contain a `administrator` and `teamid`. In my repository every call where I want to retrieve a list of data you either get the data available to your team, or all data if you're an administrator. The code to check for that is like so:

```
var content = _dataContext.Content
    .Where(c => c.teamId == teamId || isAdministrator)
    .Where(x => rest of the query here)
```

Is this a good way to implement such access restrictions? Or are there better ways to implement this?

Comment: Is it your `repository` or `controller` code? You can implement in better way this kind of access control using [`Role-based authorization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#adding-role-checks) or [`Claims-based authorization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0) these are the more elegant way. You can check for details implementation from our [`official document  here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes this is in my repository. Wouldn't that result in high duplication of queries? Then I'd have to have two functions. One for teambased queries and one for admin based queries. Or is that actually the better way?

Comment: No that's really not the `duplication of queries` this is the elegant way to handle that and its mostly used way to handle this kind of requirement. Because in yur existing code when any new role comes in you have to re-write the logic each time, which not doesn't meet the `SOLID` principle which tell us `Objects or entities should be open for extension but closed for modification`. Hope I am now clear to you.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I greatly appreciate the time you took to explain this to me. Thank you

Comment: Glad to assist you and you are most welcome. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a good way to implement such access restrictions? Or are there better ways to implement this?

You can implement in better way this kind of access control using [Role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#adding-role-checks) or [Claims-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0) these are the more elegant ways. You can check for details implementation from our [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> Wouldn't that result in high duplication of queries? Then I'd have to have two functions. One for teambased queries and one for admin based queries. Or is that actually the better way?

No that's really not the "duplication of queries" this is the elegant way to handle that and its mostly used way to handle this kind of requirement. Because in your existing code when any new role comes in you have to re-write the logic each time, which not doesn't meet the [SOLID](https://code-maze.com/open-closed-principle/) principle which tell us "Objects or entities should be open for extension but closed for modification".